# Keep access to Samba share when link to Active Directory is off

Tags: active-directory, samba, kerberos

my architecture is like that :

- a deported active directory server with replica
- a local network with Windows XP clients in Active Directory Domain
- a local Samba server member of the domain
- in samba server I can use getent to make share with acls with AD users

All works fine, when a user is authenticated in windows xp session, he can access to share whose he have rights.

Now I wants to make continuity of activitie if the link to the active directory is of. For example a user is connected at 8am to the share he works and sudenly the link is down. He can continue to access to share. But if this user logout to windows and login he can't access to share.

How can I maintain the authentication for a time (8 hours for example) to the samba share. Windows XP session can me opened if the link to the active directory is of

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

You can't. If you need authentication services at the local site in the event that the remote Domain Controllers are unavailable, then you should put a Domain Controller at the local site as well and have it replicate with the remote ones.